# The condition when the sum of consecutive product of $\pm 1$ is $0$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $N\in \Bbb N$ and $x_i = \pm1$ for all $1\leq i \leq N$.
Assume that
$$
x_1x_2+x_2x_3+\cdots+x_Nx_1 = 0
$$

How can I prove that $N$ is divisible by $4$?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking (where's $N$ from?).

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.
Furthermore, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Do you understand why $N$ is divisible by $2$?

Comment: Yes  because The number of +1 is the same as - 1

Comment: Care to engage with the answers that have been posted, Uhgv?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that there are exactly $k\le n$ products equals to $1$, then the remaining $n-k$ products are equal to $-1$. So the sum is $k-(n-k)=2k-n\equiv n \pmod 2$. So to be the sum $0$ you have the first result $n\equiv 0 \pmod 2$, i.e. $2\mid n$.

Suppose you have exactly $m$ of the $x_k$s equals to $1$ and the other $n-m$ equals to $-1$. Then you see that:
$x_1x_2+x_2x_3+...+x_nx_1=0\iff 2x_1x_2+2x_2x_3+...+2x_nx_1=0$

But $2x_1x_2+2x_2x_3+...+2x_nx_1= (x_1+x_2+...+x_n)^2-(x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2)$ so we obtain   $$(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2\iff (2m-n)^2=n\iff 4m^2-4mn+n^2=n\iff n(n-1)=n^2-n=4(mn-m^2)$$

Since $n$ and $n-1$ must be coprime $4\mid n$ or $4\mid n-1$, but $n-1$ is odd. So $n$ is multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 1):

Each $x_ix_{i+1}$ is odd, so $N$ is certainly even. We now prove if $N=4k+2$ the sum will be of the form $4l+2$. It will be if all $x_i$ are $1$ (the sum will then be $N$ so $l=k$), and each $1$ I subsequently change to a $-1$ either has no effect, due to it being multiplied by a $1$ and a $-1$ in different terms, or causes a change of size $4$ (due to multiplying $-2$ by the sum of either two $1$s or two $-1$s), i.e. $l$ changes by $1$ or $-1$.